# Compatibility issue upgrading to Windows Server 2012 (Remote Desktop Roles need uninstalled?)

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012, windows-terminal-services, upgrade

Windows Server 2012 setup (upgrading from Server 2008) says after compatibility check:

"Setup has detected that at least one of Remote Desktop Session Host (RDSH), Remote Desktop Connection Broker (RDCB), Remote Desktop Virtualization Host (RDVH) and Remote Desktop Web Access (RDWA) role is installed. To upgrade your server, uninstall these components."

I don't know what these are or how to uninstall them.  As far as I can tell, they aren't installed.  I know that the name "Terminal Services" has been replaced by "Remote Desktop", but since "Session Broker", "Gateway", and "Web Access" are all listed as "Not Installed", that leaves "Virtualization Host" unaccounted for.  It's not in the list as either installed or not installed, and they can't seriously expect me to uninstall Terminal Server itself???  What should I do?

[image: TS Role Services]

Comment: Why are you upgrading?  A clean install is almost always a better choice for servers.

Comment: That's obsolete information.  Upgrades with Windows 8 and Server 2012 as supposed to be better options that run smoothly just like Macs do, and save you all the headaches of re-configuring everything.  It's better to start with a known good configuration and upgrade.  A better question is why does it think a role is installed that's not.  I might have to do with the fact that Hyper-V was installed, but I had to uninstall it for the same reason (required to be uninstalled to upgrade).

Comment: Anyway, I am doing a clean install on an identical server sitting beside the one I'm upgrading, but my primary reason for upgrading is to avoid having to reconfigure everything and reinstall all the software.  There are a lot of obscure configuration option in SQL Server as well surrounding CLR integration options, and I just don't have time to deal with it at the moment.

Comment: The message states "at least one", hence you have at least one of these components installed, not necessarily all of these components. Your screen shot shows Terminal Server and TS Licensing. Those are the components you need to uninstall.

Comment: I know it said "at least one", but notice that none of the names exist.  No role services starting with the name "Remote Desktop" were installed, and even knowing that "Remote Desktop" == "Terminal Services", there were still service names that were unaccounted for.    Of the 4 services it complained about: "Session Host" didn't exist.  "Connection Broker" didn't exist.  "Virtualization Host" didn't exist.  And "Web Access" wasn't installed.  How the hell is anyone supposed to know that "Remote Desktop Session Host" == ("Terminal Server" + "TS Licensing").  That's my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do expect you to do so, the roles have changed dramatically and "Remote Desktop Session Host" **is** "Terminal Server", albeit in new language.

You will still be able to access your machine via remote desktop without the role installed, it will just be limited to 2 concurrent connections from administrative users.

Comment: I think its already limited to 2.  I was just hesitant to uninstall it because of the headaches I remember going through with Microsoft on the phone trying to get TS licences activated.  Do I also have to uninstall TS Licencing?

Comment: It does not say you need to remove the licensing role so I would try just removing the Terminal Server role.